# Q: ggbiplot _ Foreground arrows; change arrow color

Tags: r, ggbiplot

I have a large data set and was trying to plot a PCA. I am rather satisfied with the resulting plot, but I would like to change a couple of things:

arrows: They appear to be in the background and covered by the data points.
1) how can I foreground them?
2) how can I change the colors and fond size?

ellipses: 
3) how to make lines thicker?

legend
4) how to put in the right top of the plot itself?

Thanks in advance!!

Here is how I got that graph:

```
g <- ggbiplot(LS_3.pca, choices = 1:2, scale = 1, pc.biplot =
       TRUE, obs.scale = 1, var.scale = 1, groups =
       LS.loc, ellipse = TRUE, ellipse.prob = 0.98, labels =
       NULL, labels.size = 5, alpha = 0.25, circle
     = FALSE, circle.prob = 0.69, varname.size = 5,
     varname.adjust = 1.5, varname.abbrev = FALSE, var.axes = TRUE)
g <- g + xlim(-8, 6) + ylim(-4, 6)
g <- g + theme_classic()

print(g)
```

Answer (score 5):

ggbiplot returns an object of class "ggplot". If you examine this object, you'll find that is contains a list called "layers". The geom_segment layer appears before the geom_point layer. You want to reorder these. If the geom_segment layer is layer 2 of 4, you can do (for example):

```
myplot$layers <- c(myplot$layers, myplot$layers[[2]])
```

This will append an extra layer (that draws the arrows) at the end of the list, and this layer will be drawn after the points (in the previous layer) have been plotted. This hack is sufficient to provide the functionality you require.

EDIT: I realise this answer only covers the issue of putting the arrows in the foreground. This was a problem I encountered, and so I'm providing my solution here for others to use. To fix the other issues, I suggest typing at the console:

```
ggbiplot
```

*without the parentheses*, which will list the function body. Cut-and-paste into a new R script that defines a new function ("my_ggbiplot", for example) and hack to get what you want. It's not a long function, and it's pretty easy to figure out what everything does. However, for foregrounding the arrows, the one-line-fix above will work.

Answer (score 1):

I became frustrated by the limitations of `ggbiplot`, so copied code sections from the function to use in a standard `ggplot` call.

```
# Load data
DATA <- data.frame(iris)

# Do PCA
PCA <- prcomp(iris[,1:4])

# Extract PC axes
PCAvalues <- data.frame(Species = iris$Species, PCA$x)

# Extract loadings of the variables
PCAloadings <- data.frame(Variables = rownames(PCA$rotation), PCA$rotation)

# Calculate the angles and the label offset
PCAloadings$Angle = ((180/pi) * atan(PCAloadings$PC2/PCAloadings$PC1))
PCAloadings$Offset <- ((-2 * sign(PCAloadings$PC1))/2)

# Plot
ggplot(PCAvalues, aes(x = PC1, y = PC2, colour = Species)) +
  stat_ellipse(level = 0.95, size = 2, show.legend = FALSE) +
  geom_point(size = 3) +
  geom_segment(data = PCAloadings, aes(x = 0, y = 0, xend = (PC1), yend = (PC2)),
     arrow = arrow(length = unit(1/2, "picas")), color = "black") +
 geom_text(data = PCAloadings, aes(label = Variables, x = (PC1), y = (PC2)), 
    color = "black", size = 4, angle = PCAloadings$Angle, hjust = 
    PCAloadings$Offset) +
      theme_classic() +
      theme(legend.justification = c(1,1), legend.position = c(1,1))
```

Answers:

Q1. - as @Andrew John Lowe states in his answer, the layers are produced in the order you enter them, so if the `geom_segment` line is last, it will appear on top.

Q2. - change the arrow colour with the `colour` argument in the `geom_segment` call. Alter the font `size` of the labels in the `geom_text` call.

Q3. - again, change the `size` argument in the `stat_ellipse` call.

Q4. - the `theme` call will solve this, `c(1,1)` indicates where in the plot the legend should appear, `0` is left and `1` is right.

This is not completely ideal, in that you have to specify the `PCAloadings$Offset` for the arrow labels manually and it might take a bit of trial and error to get the desired distance, or even require entering custom numbers into the dataframe for each label. However, you are now free to use the rest of `ggplot` as you would normally.